# Service for alias emails like Air bnb or craigslist

Tags: web-services, email, sendgrid

I'm looking for a service, surprised sendgrid doesn't provide this. On our site users can send emails to other users.  We don't want to provide them with the actual email address.  Are there any services that provide email aliasing and forwarding.  The service would create an email address that could be replied to, that email would send the email immediately to the aliased address.  Stats on the emails sent would be kept but not the contents of the emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SendGrid's [Inbound Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) as an intermediary to do this.  Instead of having the users email each other directly, you can have the one user (User A) email a specified email address that receives the email.  Then, send an email to another user (User B) with the information parsed from the original email.  Here is an [example](https://github.com/devchas/sendgrid-inbound-parse-comm) of this type of communication between two users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping to not have to build this, seems like something an external service could handle.